# Flutter setState on sibling widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

In the following, my `Sort` mixin class created a list of `ItemStatefulWidget` widgets,

When a user clicks on a `ItemStatefulWidget` widget, it calls `setState()` to update the values stored in globalSortConfig, which is used by other sibling widgets.

However, `setState` didn't trigger rebuild in other sibling widgets.

***Sort Mixin Source Code:***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

dynamic globalSortConfig = null;

//
// Sort Mixin
//
mixin Sort<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  List<Widget> sortWidgets;
  dynamic mixinSorts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void showSortModal(context, Function callback) {
    // set global sort config
    if(globalSortConfig == null) {
      globalSortConfig = mixinSorts;
    }

    // show modal
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // build sort widgets 
        if (sortWidgets == null) {
          sortWidgets = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < mixinSorts.length; i++) {
            sortWidgets.add(ItemStatefulWidget(i: i, callback: callback));
          }
        }
        
        // return 
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: sortWidgets),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  
  dynamic getSortCriteria() {
    dynamic criteria = {};
    if (globalSortConfig != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < globalSortConfig.length; i++) {
        if (globalSortConfig[i]['select'] == true) {
          criteria['sort'] = globalSortConfig[i]['sort'];
          criteria['order'] = globalSortConfig[i]['order'];
        }
      }
    }
    return criteria;
  }
}
```

***ItemStatefulWidget Source code***

```
class ItemStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int i;
  final Function callback;

  ItemStatefulWidget({Key key, this.i, this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemStatefulWidgetState createState() => _ItemStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _ItemStatefulWidgetState extends State<ItemStatefulWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // var
    int i = this.widget.i;
    List<Widget> lineWidgets = [];

    // checked icon
    if (globalSortConfig[i]['select'] == true) {
      Widget iconWidget = Icon(Icons.check);
      lineWidgets.add(iconWidget);
    }

    // label
    String label =  globalSortConfig[i]['label'];

    lineWidgets.add(GestureDetector(
      child: Text(label,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {

          // update value
          globalSortConfig[i]['select'] = !globalSortConfig[i]['select'];
          for (var w = 0; w < globalSortConfig.length; w++) {
            if (w != i) {
              globalSortConfig[w]['select'] = false;
            }
          }

          // pop and callback
          Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: 900), () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            this.widget.callback();
          });
        });
      },
    ));

    // alignment
    Widget row = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: lineWidgets,
    );
    return row;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from you code what exactly the `callback` function is or does, but it is only ever called on `this.widget`, not on others.  If you want the tap of one widget to trigger changes in the others, then I think a much cleaner way to implement this is to make your `globalSortConfig` a (singleton?) object of a class that extends `ChangeNotifierProvider` from the `Provider` package.  To change your config in the `onTap` of the `ItemStatefulWidget` you can then call a method on that object that also calls `notifyListeners()`, and in the `build` method of the `ItemStatefulWidget` you listen to those changes using `context.watch`, which will ensure that each `ItemStatefulWidget` is rebuilt whenever the `globalSortConfig` object changes.